# Certain characters won't show up when written to file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a Python script takes 3 values and writes a line to a SQL file to insert those values into a database. I was specifically told I may NOT use csv writers for this. Assuming I have

```
sqlfile = open("./sqlfile.sql", "wb")
```

the commands I use to write insertion lines are as follows:

```
line = "insert into `mytable`(`value1`,`value2`,`value3`) values (\"" + variable1 + "\",\"" + variable2 + "\",\"" + variable3 + "\");\n"
sqlfile.write(line)
```

(It's worth noting that all three are string values) For this example I'll set variable1 = AAA, variable2 = BBB, and variable3 = CCC. When it is run, the script prints like this:

```
insert into `mytable`(`value1``value2``value3`) values ("AAA"BBBCCC);
```

In other words, none of the commas print. Even more frustrating, the quotes DO print, but only the first set - the second and third set are ignored just like the commas. I also tried doing something like `variable1 + "\"" + "," + "\"" + variable2`, as well as that with `\`, instead of just `,` however this didn't work either. The frustrating thing is I've written to other files in this project and used commas and quotes, and it worked before. I'm pretty new to Python and especially to using it to write to and from files, so I can't figure out why this happens. I preliminary search of the web didn't help much either. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Also, I tried this with writing one part at a time, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why do you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: I tried it with 'w' and 'wb', neither work. That was just the latest I tried.

Comment: Odd. The commas should be written. The file mode should make no difference. Are you sure that's the *exact* code? (Also, using `format` can clean it up alot.)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. And yes, I copy and pasted to a separate file, then did a find/replace on variable names. I was hoping it's just something simple I'm overlooking, but I'm starting to feel like maybe it isn't haha

Comment: @thnkwthprtls How is the file being viewed? What happens if writing directly the terminal (e.g. `sys.stdout.write`)?

Comment: I've been using UltraEdit to view the completed SQL files, when it goes right to STDOUT it also doesn't have the quotes or commas

Comment: @thnkwthprtls Even more .. interesting. Was this code *typed* in or copied? My last remaining thought (if it is indeed the current code, and does indeed behave the same way when writing to stdout) is that there is some funny Unicode/encoding play.

Comment: When I run this code, the commas and quotes are definitely there. Are you sure this is the same code you're running? When you write things like `"\","\""` instead of `'","'` (or, even more simply, using `format` instead of `+`), it's very easy to make mistakes, and very hard to spot them.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, like I said though I just copy and pasted from the code that doesn't work

Comment: @thnkwthprtls: I don't believe this is your real code. [Here](http://repl.it/Mbi/3) you can see that exact line of code running online, and it produces the commas and quotes as it does on my local Python 2.7 and 3.3 interpreters and in the heads of everyone reading your code.

Comment: More importantly, if you realize that this code is hard to read and easy to get wrong, why not just change it into something easier to read and harder to get wrong, instead of trying to debug it as-is?

Comment: As a side note, [what are you actually trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why are you generating a SQL script file with embedded values to insert? Because there may be a better way to do whatever you're trying to do. (For example, if you just want to generate a setup script that inserts 1000 rows into a table, maybe you'd be better off build up a table in a local database, with a parameterized SQL statement and `executemany`, and then `DUMP`ing it to a SQL script to transfer to the real database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line, as pasted here, does the right thing.

You can see it running at [repl.it](http://repl.it/Mbi/3). The output is:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jul 20 2011, 02:32:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM, Emscripten 1.5, Empythoned)] on linux2

insert into `mytable`(`value1`,`value2`,`value3`) values ("AAA","BBB","CCC");
```

However, there are any number of ways you could have gotten this wrong in your actual code that would be nearly impossible to spot, because you've chosen the least readable (and writable) way to do this.

If you want to include double quotes in a string, instead of escaping the quotes, just use a single-quoted string:

```
line = 'insert into `mytable`(`value1`,`value2`,`value3`) values ("' + variable1 + '","' + variable2 + '","' + variable3 + '");\n'
```

Or, even better, get rid of the string concatenation so you don't have to deal with all those short strings with quotes inside quotes:

```
line = 'insert into `mytable`(`value1`,`value2`,`value3`) values ("{}","{}","{}");\n'.format(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

Neither of these changes fixes the problem in your posted code, because there *is* no problem in your current code. But it will most likely fix the problem in your actual code, because whichever of the many possible mistakes you might have made in the actual code will be harder to make, and easier to spot if you do make it.

Comment: I tried first solution and seems to give correct output, thanks. Still have no idea why it wasn't working, that's literally the only thing I changes, but as long as it works that's what's important haha

Comment: @thnkwthprtls: I'm 100% sure that your original code wasn't working because it wasn't the same as the code you posted here. The fact that you can stare at them and still not find any differences is not proof that you reproduced it correctly, it's an illustration of the very reason you shouldn't write code this way.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe try closing the file?
Or even better, use context manager?

```
with open(<path>, <mode>) as f:
    f.write("abc")
```

If you dont know what that means - try googling.

Comment: I do know what it mean, I just tried that format and that didn't work either. Neither did closing it.

Comment: He definitely _does_ need to fix this; otherwise he could end up with an empty or incomplete file. (The file won't be flushed until it's closed, and if you don't close it explicitly, it won't be closed until the last reference is deleted, and Python doesn't guarantee to cleanly delete all references at shutdown.) But still, this is obviously a _separate_ problem, not the one he's asking about; there's no way leaving the file unflushed could remove quotes and commas from the middle of what he wrote… So, this is a comment, not an answer.